# MDX convert number to string / concat mixed type

Tags: ssas, mdx

How would I do the following cast operation?

```
CAST(Season) + PlayerSlug
```

`PlayerSlug` is of type `System.String` and `Season` is of type `System.Int32`. I want the result to be something like:

```
"2014-TomJones"
```

How would I do this? Doing a straight concat returns a type of `Int32` instead of string:

```
PlayerSlug + Season
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need this on MDX you can try to use Member_Name and check if it's WChar (by default it's WChar even for integer keys).

[image: Member Name type]

Test query:

```
with member [Year_Country]
as [Date].[Year].CurrentMember.Member_Name
+" - "+[Location].[Country].CurrentMember.Member_Name
select
 [Year_Country] on 0
,[Location].[Country].Members*[Date].[Year].Members on 1
from [My_Cube]
```

Result is:

[image: Member Name concat result]

Answer (score 0):

Try **CStr()** and **CInt()** to convert to string and int.
E.g. CStr(Season) + PlayerSlug